# p values and lists in python

Tags: python, list, mongodb, statistics

I have a large data set of numbers which are embedded in documents. I want to extract them all, put them in an ordered list, and then return to each document its "pvalue": which is its order in the sorted list divided by the length of the list.
I am having a lot of trouble figuring out how to do this within a python code.

```
movie_records = db.movies.find()
list=[]

for i in movie_records:
    num = i["total_tickets"]

    #put them all in a list, order the list


for i in movie_records:
    number=i["total_tickets"]
    tickets_pvalue= 1 - ( #position of number /len(list) )
    shows.update({"id":i["id"]}, {'$set':{"total_tickets_pvalue":tickets_pvalue}})
```

Comment: How do you want to order the list?

Comment: What is "the order in the sorted list"? Do you mean its index in the sorted list?

Comment: I want to order the list from the smallest number to the largest one. Basically the p-value of a number N is the probability that a randomly chosen number from the dataset will be larger than N. So the index needs to start at 1. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: @Julia Where is this number coming from? Is that `i["total_tickets"]`? If so, why don't you just query mongo for it, so python gets it in order?

Comment: yes exactly, it is i["total_tickets"]

Comment: What do you get if you do `movie_records = db.movies.find(sort='total_tickets')` instead? (If that doesn't work, try `movie_records = db.movies.find(sort=['total_tickets', 1])`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Barring any knowledge of mongodb (you'd be better off doing the sorting by it, as suggested in the comments):

```
movie_records = sorted([(m['total_tickets'], m) for m in db.movies.find()])

# Select distinct on total_tickets
distinct_records = []
prev = None
while movie_records:
    record = movie_records.pop(0)
    if record[0] != prev:
        prev = record[0]
        distinct_records.append(record[1])

for index, movie in enumerate(distinct_records):
    tickets_pvalue = 1 - (index + 1.0) / len(distinct_records)
    shows.update({"id": movie["id"]},
                 {'$set': {"total_tickets_pvalue": tickets_pvalue}})
```

Comment: Instead of creating a list of tuples and sorting that, you could do: `movie_records = sorted(db.movies.find(), cmp=lambda x,y: cmp(x['total_tickets'], y['total_tickets']))`

Comment: Thank you, although I don't seem to make it work as it returns a p-value of 1 for all the documents. I know it's not rounding up since it even returns 1 for movies with no tickets sold.

Comment: My bad! There was some integer division going on. Edited the snippet

Comment: Last question, @JessetheGame : in order for my p-value to be correct, i would need to remove from the list multiple occurences of the 'total_tickets' value i am looking at. Would you mind telling me how i could do it? Thank you so much!

Comment: You should really be starting to look into mongodb to do this work for you. Database adapters are usually very efficient at sorting and filtering (in this case ORDER BY and DISTINCT on total_tickets). I'll add a quick n dirty solution to the snippet, but go and look at mongodb solutions if you have the time.

Comment: @JessetheGame I'm in the process of learning mongodb but haven't gotten to aggregations yet :) i will have a look! thank you!